# MacOS project on desktop loses node_modules

Tags: macos, npm

I was wondering if anyone else has come across subfolders of node_modules randomly disappearing on Mac, not the entire directory but the odd dependency?

All my projects are on my desktop and randomly I get errors running a project where a node module has suddenly disappeared, I say disappeared but they actually appear to be there, the only way I've figured of correcting the issue is to delete the entire node_modules directory and reinstall?

I can't say I've ever come across this previously, my desktop does backup to iCloud, aside from that I can't think of anything else that would cause this - any ideas?

Comment: And a vote to close because it's not about programming, I'm a professional programmer and my node_modules keep unlinking on MacOS only, I don't quite see why the confusion?

Comment: Hey look, here's another downvote, for being rude. Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks Charles, you're a star!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out for anyone that has the issue you need to disable iCloud backup/sync on the folders with your node modules projects, somehow MacOS seems to break the folder structure - I'm not quite sure why yet...